# Why should I unbind Javascript Events?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, unbind

Could anyone explain **why** I should unbind or detach Javascript Events?

Comment: Can you give us a code example or a scenario?

Comment: in most cases you don't need to unbind at all. for others - see Jonas H's answer.

Comment: If you downvote my question explain why!

Comment: @AugustLilleaas It's just a generic question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because you simply no longer want the events to fire
2. Because they take up memory. Note that in old versions of IE, manual unbinding may be needed for memory to be freed, even if the elements are removed from the DOM.

Comment: One use case for unbinding events would be drag & drop. You only want to listen to "mousemove" on an element while the left mouse button is down, for example. And unbinding the event is better than checking `if (isDragging) { ... }` in the event listener, simply because it's a built-in way of doing just that.